# How to get all word permutaions using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria, query-by-example

I want to create a hibernate query using hql or criteria to get all permutations of a word, for the word `elepahant`  i want to get:

- eliphant
- ilephant
- iliphant
- elefant

at first i assumed that `"%" + "elepahant" + "%"` could do the work but in fact it only returns any word that starts with any letter and ends with any letter and containing `elephant` in-between, but i want to get all the word reseambles like the example above, so what are the possible ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Hibernate Search, Lucene, Spell Checker. I don't think you can do such things with simple SQL.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.3/reference/en-US/html/

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to use a denormalized field with the word sorted alphabetically like this:

```
word   sorted_word
apple  aelpp
kitty  iktty
```

And just compare the sorted word against that column.